# Is there a way of passing messages to different processes which allows for multiple producers and consumers?

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, multiprocessing

Hi I was wondering if there was a module in python that would allow a queue system between processes that could pass messages as input and output. Ideally I would like to start the queue and store it in a var that stays blocking until the queue handler can handle the input and returns with the output. This would then set the var to whatever was returned by the queue handler.

Something like this:

Queue.py

```
Data = 0
x = Queue(Data)
print(x)
```

QueueHand.py

```
def foo(z):
        z += 1
        return z

while True:
        y = queue.get()
        y.foo()
```

Output:
`1`

This should be able to handle multiple processes running queue.py.

Comment: you can use Queue module

Comment: I looked at the Queue module but it only allowed one way messaging